# Missing fonts in PDF created and saved in Illustrator -- not outlines, the actual fonts

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, pdf

I have a PDF that is editable in Illustrator. I have to open the PDF in Illustrator and edit individual parts of the document but I am missing the font that is used in the PDF. When I open the PDF in Illustrator, the PDF opens but the font is automatically replaced with a substitute font.

How do I get the original fonts?  Can they be extracted as the original fonts, even though I do not have them in my system?  I need the fonts that were used when the document was created.  Not outlines, the actual fonts.

Comment: Some fonts are free, but a big part of fonts is created for earning money. You obviously have met that in practice. You cannot find the missing font in PDF, only its name, you must buy and install a copy. See the suggested duplicate candidate.

Answer (score 0):

You end up buying them - that's the long and the short of it. You look in the font file, and somewhere there will be information on the font foundry which created it, or you look up online, and you purchase as much of the font as you need - if you're not an active graphic designer using this font in a wide range of applications, you may get by with the cheapest subset, or if you can see yourself using it a lot, buy the whole thing.